# How to insert an html object in a div's text at a certain position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which contains some user input text.

I want to be able to insert an html object, span lets say at a certain position in this div's text.

For example:

```
<div>
    There is some text in this div and I would like to append an html object right here.
    There might be some other text here.
</div>
```

To turn it into:

```
<div>
    There is some text in this div and I would like to append an html object <span class="safeHtml"></span> right here.
    There might be some other text here.
</div>
```

Some things to take into account:

1. I dont want to render the whole div as safe html, since the user input can contain html tags that can ruin my design or some nasty scripts.
2. I want to render as html just the inserted object; the rest as text.

Thanks

PS: Specific enough now or should I draw a picture on a chalkboard for the ones who closed the question and downvoters?

Comment: You can do this with a simple string replace.

Comment: You should modify the innerHTML of the div

Comment: i edited my question, see above pls.. and why the down vote?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to replace `right here` :

```
$('div').each(function(){
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/right here/, '<span>something</span>'));
});
```

If you want to just insert, you may do :

```
$('div').each(function(){
  var html = $(this).html();
  var i = html.indexOf('right here');
  if (i>=0) $(this).html(html.slice(0, i)+'<span>something</span>'+html.slice(i));
});
```

Comment: i updated my question, see above pls

Comment: this will still render the div content as safe html

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble understanding the question. But I think, this is what you are looking for.
http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/wzBh3/

HTML

```
<div>
    Some text. <span id="newText"> </span> .Some more text.
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var htmlObject = "Text from HTML object"; 
$("#newText").append(htmlObject);
```